# nginx: Map single static URL to a PHP file ?No input file specified

Tags: php, nginx, configuration

I need to Map single static URL to a specific PHP file i am using following in config file

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location /reset {
           root html/sys;
           try_files /index.php /index.php;
            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000; //PHP server
            fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
            fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD   $request_method;
            fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE     $content_type;
            fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH   $content_length;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;    
            include         fastcgi_params;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

Result = ("No input file specified.") in response

If i would return ( try_files index.html; ) and remove php proxy then it would return html index page this problem only occurs when it tries to return php page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the document root to `html/sys` which is relative to the Nginx installation. It's probable that PHP-FPM doesn't know how to resolve that.

Either use an absolute path:

```
root /path/to/html/sys;
```

Or use `$realpath_root` which is an absolute version of `$document_root`:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Or use `$request_filename` which is less typing:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
```

You should place `include fastcgi_params;` **before** your `fastcgi_param` statements, as your parameters may be silently overwritten by values specified in that file.

Comment: Thanks for responding
I added the root to c:\\nginx-1.14.2\\html\\sys and tried c:/nginx-1.14.2/html/sys 
then changed fastcgi_param but still getting No input file specified.

Comment: When i run fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME c:\\nginx-1.14.2\\html\\sys\\index.php
it works so as you said it has to do with an absolute path:
Thanks alot Richard Smith
!Please vote on him i have to little rep